# Cannot multiply a numeric and matrix using *

Tags: rstudio

I have two objects: a vector `kw` with length 2517 and a matrix `W.mat` with dimensions 2517x9. I am trying to do the operation in RStudio: `kw * W.mat` which gives the error:

> "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

I tried making a smaller vector and matrix and multiplying them using the `*` operator, which works properly. Why can't I multiply my specific two objects, `kw` and `W.mat`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided, it seems that it could be two things:

- Either `kw` or `W.mat` isn't numeric to begin with: If any of the elements in your `kw` vector or `W.mat` matrix are not numeric (e.g., characters, factors), R will throw this error.
- Sometimes, objects in R can have attributes or structures that make them non-numeric, even if they appear to contain only numeric values. For example, a vector could be a factor or a date, internally represented differently.